# Let $ \Omega = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : | x | \leq 1 \} $. Show that the function $ v(x) = |x|^{\alpha} $ belong to $ H^1(\Omega) $ if $ \alpha > 0 $

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Let $ \Omega = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : | x | \leq 1 \} $. Show that the function $ v(x) = |x|^{\alpha} $ belong to $ H^1(\Omega)  $ if $ \alpha > 0 $.

We know that:

$$ \mathbb{L}_2(\Omega)  = \{ v: v \ \text{its defined in} \  \Omega \ \text{and} \ \int_{\Omega} v^2 dx < \alpha \} $$

and that

$$ H^1(\Omega) = \{ v \in \mathbb{L}_2 (\Omega) : \frac{\partial v}{ \partial x_i} \in \mathbb{L}_2(\Omega) , i = 1 , 2 , \ldots , d \} $$

where $ d  \text{ comes from }  R^d $

I did'nt understand how to solve this problem, i have tried numerically but my teacher says that im going in the wrong direction

Appreciate any help

thanks

Comment: First question: do you know that $v \in L^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: yes, what you can deduce from that ?

Comment: i've thought that i would have to prove that when $\alpha \leq 0 $ it does not belong to $ \mathbb{L}_2 (\Omega)$ .

Comment: Good. Second question: what is $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}$?

Comment: the partial derivative of $v$ with respect to $x_i$ in this case $x_1 , x_2$

Comment: but is not continuous when we have $ \alpha < 0 $ and $ x = 0 $. and what about when $ \alpha = 0 $ ?

Comment: it's because we have the partial derivative of $1$ with respect to any value equals to zero?

Comment: Away from the origin $v(x)$ is classically differentiable. You need to be able to calculate $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}$.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!